# Determining the number of terms in the result of the multiplication of two polynomials

Tags: c++, polynomial-math

This is a program c++ which is performing different operations on polynomials. Here in this program there is a logical problem in the `multiplication()` function. I am not able to figure out the number of terms in the resultant polynomial which is the result of multiplication of two polynomials.

This program is giving correct multiplied outputs for most of the cases, but there are few cases in which the multiplication is not being performed correctly. Below is the full program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct poly
{
    int coef, pow;
};

int k=0;
poly* getdata(poly *a,int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n Enter the coefficient and power of the term";
        cin>>a[i].coef>>a[i].pow;
    }
    return a;
}

poly* add(poly *c, poly *a, poly *b, int n1, int n2)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2)
    {
        if(a[i].pow<b[j].pow)
        {
            c[k].pow = a[i].pow;
            c[k].coef = a[i].coef;
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else if(a[i].pow == b[j].pow)
        {
            c[k].pow = a[i].pow;
            c[k].coef = a[i].coef+b[j].coef;
            i++; j++; k++;
        }
        else
            //(a[i].pow > b[j].pow)
        {
            c[k].pow = b[j].pow;
            c[k].coef = b[j].coef;
            j++; k++;
        }
    }
    while(i<n1)
    {
        c[k].pow = a[i].pow;
        c[k].coef = a[i].coef;
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<n2)
    {
        c[k].pow = b[j].pow;
        c[k].coef = b[j].coef;
        j++; k++;
    }
    return c;
}

void display(poly *p,int n)
{
    int i;
    cout<<"\n The polynomial is :-\n";
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        cout<<p[i].coef<<"x^"<<p[i].pow<<"+";
    }
    cout<<p[i].coef<<"x^"<<p[i].pow;
    cout<<endl;
}

void multiplication(poly *c, poly *a, poly* b, int n1, int n2)
{
    int i, j;
    //int count = 0;

    for(i=0; i<n1*n2; i++)
    {
        c[i].coef = 0;
        c[i].pow = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
        {
            c[i+j].coef = a[i].coef*b[j].coef + c[i+j].coef;
            c[i+j].pow = a[i].pow + b[j].pow;
        }
    }
    //return count;
}

int main()
{
    poly a[10], b[10], c[10];
    poly *p, *q , *result;
    int n1, n2;
    cout<<"\n Enter the number of terms in polynomial 1 : ";
    cin>>n1;
    p = getdata(a,n1);
    display(p, n1);

    cout<<"\n Enter the number of terms in polynomial 2 : ";
    cin>>n2;
    q = getdata(b,n2);
    display(q, n2);

    result = add(c, a, b, n1, n2);
    cout<<"\n The Sum of the two polynomial is ";
    display(result, k);

    poly *mresult;
    mresult = new poly[n1+n2];
    multiplication(mresult, a, b, n1, n2);
    cout<<"\n The Multiplication of the two polynomials is :- ";
    display(mresult,n1+n2-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output in few cases :-

```
 Enter the number of terms in polynomial 1 : 2

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term1
1

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term3
9

 The polynomial is :-
1x^1+3x^9

 Enter the number of terms in polynomial 2 : 2

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term1
3

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term2
6

 The polynomial is :-
1x^3+2x^6

 The Sum of the two polynomial is 
 The polynomial is :-
1x^1+1x^3+2x^6+3x^9

 The Multiplication of the two polynomials is :- 
 The polynomial is :-
1x^4+5x^12+6x^15
```

this is correct.
But consider this case :-

```
 Enter the number of terms in polynomial 1 : 2

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term1
1

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term3
9

 The polynomial is :-
1x^1+3x^9

 Enter the number of terms in polynomial 2 : 2

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term1
3

 Enter the coefficient and power of the term2
6

 The polynomial is :-
1x^3+2x^6

 The Sum of the two polynomial is 
 The polynomial is :-
1x^1+1x^3+2x^6+3x^9

 The Multiplication of the two polynomials is :- 
 The polynomial is :-
1x^4+5x^12+6x^15
```

this is wrong . Here the multiplication should be :- `x^4+2x^7+3x^12+6x^15`

there are few more logic which i have tried eg:-

```
int multiplication(poly *c, poly *a, poly* b, int n1, int n2)
{
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;

    for(i=0; i<n1*n2; i++)
    {
        c[i].coef = 0;
        c[i].pow = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
        {
            c[count].coef = a[i].coef*b[j].coef + c[count].coef;
            c[count].pow = a[i].pow + b[j].pow;
            if(c[count].pow != c[count-1].pow) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

this function is returning the number of terms in the polynomial c.

Note :- c is the result of the multiplication of the two polynomials a and b.

Comment: You have some apparent redundancy in the representation of polynomials. Is it ever the case that the term at index K has a power other than K?

Comment: Try treating it as just adding a term for each combination of the original polynomial's terms first.  Once you have that working, see how you could combine terms with the same power.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't get you sir. I think Ofcourse there may be several cases i which the power will be different.

Comment: @VaughnCato: sir, i tried you that too. But I'm unable to do that properly. My second implementation is implementing what you said. If you can give a short algo. for that i will be thankful to you.

Comment: Stop with the "sir", please

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry to say, but may know what's wrong with saying sir? Don't just ignore it just reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *f* and *g* are polynomials of *x*, the degree of *f* × *g* is the degree of *f* plus the degree of *g*.  The coefficients of the resulting polynomial will be the sum of several pairs of products; *e.g.* when multiplying (f_2 x^2 + f_1 x + f_0)(g_2 x^2 + g_1 x + g_0), the coefficient of x^2 will be f_2*g_0 + f_1*g_1 + f_0*g_2.  You will not know in advance whether these sum up to zero.  The binomial (x+1)(x+1) has three nonzero terms, but (x+1)(x-1) has two, and (x^2+1)(x^4+x^3) has four.

You can efficiently calculate this polynomial by summing its coefficients in a vector whose index is the degree of each term.  You can eliminate terms identical to zero when and if you convert back.

Answer (score 0):

You want logic that is more like this:

```
for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
    {
        int coef = a[i].coef * b[j].coef;
        int pow = a[i].pow + b[j].pow;
        count = add_term_to(c,count,coef,pow);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to implement `add_term_to()` such that it combines terms with the same power.

Comment: thank's for telling me the outlook of the problem , but the main idea lies in the definition of function add_term_to(c, count, coef, pow) . I was trying to do the same but without using the function. So if you can add a little to the function body then I think it may help me completely.

Comment: @AryanKhan: You just need to see if there is already a term with the same power.  If so, add the coefficient to the existing term, otherwise add a new term.

Comment: I implemented this :-
is this right?

int add_term_to(poly* c, int coef, int pow, int count)
{
 c[count].coef += coef;
 c[count].pow = pow;
 if(c[count].pow != c[count-1].pow && c[count].coef !=0)
 {
  count++;
 }
 return count;
}

Comment: @AryanKhan: You are assuming that if there is a term with a matching power, it will be at the end, but this may not be true.